# I use Rhubarb lip sync with blender. But they are changing the pose library. Will there be support for Rhubarb in the new Blender?

Tags: animation

The new changes to the pose library have left the old library listed as legacy. I am thinking they may delete this. But it is necessary for the operation of Rhubarb.
Does anyone know if there will be support for Rhubarb? Maybe there is a work around I am not familiar with?

Comment: yes, the old pose library is subject to be removed in Blender 3.3. But in my 3.3 beta, it's still there with the reminder note. For an update of the addon it's better to ask here: https://github.com/scaredyfish/blender-rhubarb-lipsync/issues/45

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I see they are well aware of the problem. Hopefully a solution will be in the near future.